# Biometrika journal style file not getting along with TeXLive-2020

Tags: ntheorem, texlive-2020

I cannot compile styleguide.tex in biometrika.zip (see https://academic.oup.com/biomet/pages/General_Instructions).

Here is a MWE which leads to the same error message, though not sure yet that I've not tossed baby out with bath water.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\makeatletter
\def\arabic#1{{\rm\expandafter\@arabic\csname c@#1\endcsname}}
\theoremnumbering{arabic}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
This is a definition.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output of `pdflatex`:

```
% pdflatex styleguide
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./styleguide.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./ntheorem.sty

Style `ntheorem', Version 1.24 <2004/09/20>
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def
) (./styleguide.aux)
! Use of \@item doesn't match its definition.
\update@series@target@value #1->\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #1}\ifx \target@meta@famil...
l.13 T
      his is a definition.
? q
OK, entering \batchmode
```

Comment: redefining \arabic like this is wrong; there shouldn't be a font command there. Too many packages assume that \arabic gives a more or less plain number. It perhaps worked by chance in older systems, but now it explodes as some internals of the font selection changed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `biometrika` class file makes (at least) three bad errors:

1. it uses `\rm` all around, notwithstanding that the command has been deprecated for 25 years (well, 14 according to the release date, but it's long time anyway);
2. it redefines `\document`, which is even worse;
3. it does `\def\arabic#1{{\rm\expandafter\@arabic\csname c@#1\endcsname}}` which cannot be commented on a public site.

Really, error number 3 is something that any LaTeX programmer should know to stay away from. About number 2, the purpose of the class seems to be just to remove

```
  \ifx\normalsfcodes\@empty
    \ifnum\sfcode`\.=\@m
      \let\normalsfcodes\frenchspacing
    \else
      \let\normalsfcodes\nonfrenchspacing
    \fi
  \fi
  \ifx\document@default@language\m@ne
    \chardef\document@default@language\language
  \fi
```

(checked with `latex.ltx` from TeX Live 2007), so there is no reason whatsoever for doing it.

How to fix it?

Here's a suitable preamble that makes `\rm` into a no-op, so all explicit occurrences in the document has to be replaced by the correct command (`\mathrm` in math mode).

```
%%% fix the plain theorem style to have numbers upright
\RequirePackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\makeatletter
\renewtheoremstyle{plain} 
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ \textup{##2}\theorem@separator]} 
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ \textup{##2}\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother

%%% save \document and \arabic to be reinstated after loading the class
\let\latexdocument\document
\let\latexarabic\arabic

%%% load the class (use the option you need)
\documentclass[manuscript]{biometrika}
%\documentclass[lineno]{biometrika}

%%% reinstate the original \document and \arabic
\let\document\latexdocument
\let\arabic\latexarabic

%%% make \rm into a no-op
\def\rm{}
```

Then one can go on with the other needed packages for the document and the body of the document.

Note that the author of the class *knows* about `\renewtheoremstyle`!

Comment: you are a hero.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
This is a definition.
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

does not raise any problem. Seems that they are trying to use ntheorem in a nonstandard way.