# Extra \endgroup when using the Biometrika template

Tags: templates, mactex, lineno

I recently downloaded the Biometrika 2020 template to use to typeset a paper (please see: Stylistic Requirement here: https://academic.oup.com/biomet/pages/General_Instructions ).

When typesetting, I get the following error:

! Extra \endgroup.
\document ->\endgroup
\ifx @unusedoptionlist @empty \else @latex@warning@...
l.46 \begin{document}

The document class is:

\documentclass[lineno]{biometrika}

and I get this error when using both TeXShop and TeX Studio. I have also recently upgraded to Big Sur iOS, and both my TexShop (TeXLive 2020) and TeX Studio are the latest versions.

This is followed by a host of other red flags. I am not very savvy in LaTeX, and would like to seek help on how to solve this problem.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `biometrika` class redefines `\document`, which is a serious sin, and in a way that's not compatible with the current LaTeX release.

Answer (score 5):

The `biometrika` class does several nasty things, the worst of which are redefining `\document` and `\enddocument` for no apparent reason.

This makes it incompatible with the current LaTeX kernel. But you can fix it.

```
%%% save the original kernel definitions
\let\latexarabic\arabic
\let\latexdocument\document
\let\latexenddocument\enddocument

%%% fix for bad usage of ntheorem
\RequirePackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\makeatletter
\renewtheoremstyle{plain} 
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ \textup{##2}\theorem@separator]} 
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ \textup{##2}\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother

%%% now we can load the class

%\documentclass[manuscript]{biometrika}
\documentclass[
  supplementary,
  lineno
]{biometrika}

%%% recover the original definitions
\let\document\latexdocument
\let\enddocument\latexenddocument
\AtEndDocument{\printhistory}
\let\arabic\latexarabic
\def\rm{}

%%% now we can go on with the rest of the document
```

Remember to never use `\rm` in your document, which I'm sure you don't, because the command has been deprecated for more than 25 years.

Related: [Biometrika journal style file not getting along with TeXLive-2020](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/563415/4427)