# Strange !Extra \endgroup error

Tags: errors, document-classes, miktex-update

I believe similar issues have been raised after a recent update before, but I couldn't find anything that fixes my issue, so I'm posting it here.

I'm trying to run the Review of Finance Latex template as

```
%\documentclass[manuscript]{roffin}
\documentclass{roffin}


\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

which results in the error

```
! Extra \endgroup.
\document ->\endgroup 
                      \ifx \@unusedoptionlist \@empty \else \@latex@warning@...
l.5 \begin{document}
```

I have tried again after update/ restart, alas no success. Strangely, the error only occurs for my office machine, which runs MikTex and not at my own machine, which runs  MacTex.

Does anyone have any ideas what to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  The `roffin` class seems to redefine some LaTeX internals which changed with the last release.  Where is this `roffin` class available from?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The template is from the PDF of the journal author guidelines. It downloads automatically following this  [link](https://static.primary.prod.gcms.the-infra.com/static/site/rof/document/ROFFIN.zip?node=c9e94493854df236b202&version=117255:13278eb94afc4a0ae205).

Comment: The `\document` macro is defined exactly equal to Biometrika `\document`. See related post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575327/

Comment: Thanks for that. As it turns out, there is an updated version that is linked to from the website version of the author guide. Apparently the PDF has been out of date.